# Excel / C - get input with array*

Tags: c, arrays, excel, xll

I'm working on a simple XLL addin and trying to get the input with a regular double* (not FP or OPER) because from what I understand, Excel should work with regular C data types. I can't get it to work, after many modifications, now it only returns the value in my last cell. What am I doing wrong?\

```
static AddIn xai_array_try(
    "?xll_array_try", XLL_DOUBLE XLL_DOUBLE_,
    "ARRAY.TRY", "Array",
    "STL", "Test Sum Array."
    );

double WINAPI xll_array_try(const double *arr) {
#pragma XLLEXPORT

    int i;
    double sum = 0;

    int size = 3;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

If I would get it as a FP or OPER, would I be able then to pass it to a function that takes input as array?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is the size of the pointer, e.g. 4 or 8.

Comment: ok, i'm changing it to a number like 3 since it's only for testing. now i get "Access violation reading location"

Comment: how much elements does `arr` have?

Comment: i'm only typing in 3. now it only returns the value in my 3rd cell

Comment: How is `arr` declared? like `double arr[3];`?

Comment: const double *arr. it's supposed to come from the excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687869(v=office.12).aspx)

my addin output was wrong, and my function input was wrong.

```
static AddIn xai_array_try(
    "?xll_array_try", XLL_DOUBLE "O%",
    "ARRAY.TRY", "Array",
    "STL", "Test Sum Array."
    );

double WINAPI xll_array_try(int *rows, int *columns, double *arr) {
#pragma XLLEXPORT

    int i;
    double sum = 0;

    int size = *rows * *columns;

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```